# Rebel of while in php

Tags: php, web, while-loop

This code shows the contents of a mysql database table and has a button  further down the form, but unfortunately, while I and my revolts $ a variable is always the final value.

Example post about id = 1, click on the button when the address of the page + variable.

See table is 11 or variable which is at the exit of the loop.

How to link to pages with the whole post with id 1 looked so looks.
php example? Id = '1'

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';
    $a = 0;
    $conn = @new mysqli($host, $dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_errno!=0)
    {
         echo "Error ".$conn->connect_errno;
    } else {
         $id=$_SESSION["id"];
         #echo 'to jest nasze id '.$id;
         $sql = "select * from zgloszenia where user_id ='$id'; ";
         $wynik = $conn->query($sql);
         echo '<table class="table table-striped"><tr><th>id</th><th>stan</th><th>opis</th><th>data</th></tr>';

         while($row = $wynik->fetch_assoc()) {
                $t[]=$row['id'];
                echo "<tr href='http://myspace.com'><td>".$row['id'].
                     "</td><td>".$row['stan']."</td><td>".$row['opis'].
                     "</td><td>".$row['data_zgl'].
                     "</td><td><form method ='post'><button  type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-default'>zobacz</button></form></td></tr>";

                 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                      header('Location: zobacz.php?id='.$t[0].'');
                 }
                 $a++;
           }
           echo '</table>';

    }
    print_r($t);
    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Eh... What? Could you perhaps clarify your question again and a tad clearer?

Comment: i think i got it what he is trying to achieve, `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` inside loop, so i think he is trying to go to `header('Location: zobacz.php?id='.$t[0].'');` when submit the button

Comment: @Shehary Well edit the question so other can see what you think, he thinks, he means

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can't edit the question but i figure out what he is trying to do just by looking at code

Comment: I would like to be with each line could look to the individual variable could be go to the website of the variables in the link to view the database, all data on this variable

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you are trying to say about your problem and what you are trying to achieve but looking at the code, can assume you are trying to go to page where you can fetch detail from database against specific `id` and again by looking at your code you are trying to add link in `<tr>` tag and then trying to post the `id` with form assuming it will take you to targeted page with `id`

Couple of things about your approach

- you don't need array to achieve this like you are trying here `$t[]=$row['id'];`
- `<a>` tag or `href` won't work out of  the box inside `<tr>` tag
- The way you are trying to add form inside `loop` and redirecting with `header location` won't work.
- and do not mix HTML with PHP, it make things more complicated

Try any one of following solution, which ever suits your need.

**Solution-1**

I added a button at the end of each row, clicking on button will take you targeted page with `id`.

Here `<a href='pagename.php?id= ".$row['id']."'>Button</a>` you need to change `href='pagename.php` to correct page name.

```
<?php session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
$a = 0;
$conn = @new mysqli($host, $dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno!=0){
     echo "Error ".$conn->connect_errno;
} else {
    $id=$_SESSION["id"];
    //echo 'to jest nasze id '.$id;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM zgloszenia WHERE user_id='$id'";
    $wynik = $conn->query($sql);
    echo '<table class="table table-striped">
         <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>stan</th>
            <th>opis</th>
            <th>data</th>
            <th>Button</th>
         </tr>';
     while($row = $wynik->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>         
                    <td>".$row['stan']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['opis']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['data_zgl']."</td>
                    <td><a href='pagename.php?id= ".$row['id']."'>Button</a></td>";
             $a++;
             echo "</tr>";
       }
       echo '</table>';
}
print_r($t);
$conn->close();
?>
```

**Solution-2**

I make `<tr>` tag click able with javas-cript and remove form, so each row is clickable and take you to targeted page

Here `<tr onclick='window.location='pagename.php?id= ".$row['id']."''>` you need to change `href='pagename.php` to correct page name.

```
<?php session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';
$a = 0;
$conn = @new mysqli($host, $dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_errno!=0){
     echo "Error ".$conn->connect_errno;
} else {
     $id=$_SESSION["id"];
     //echo 'to jest nasze id '.$id;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM zgloszenia WHERE user_id='$id'";
     $wynik = $conn->query($sql);

    echo '<table class="table table-striped">
         <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>stan</th>
            <th>opis</th>
            <th>data</th>
         </tr>';

     while($row = $wynik->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr onclick='window.location='pagename.php?id= ".$row['id']."''>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>         
                    <td>".$row['stan']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['opis']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['data_zgl']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        $a++;
       }
       echo '</table>';
}
print_r($t);
$conn->close();
?>
```